# What does the following highlighted sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I was reading a book on learning programming languages called *The Complete ASP.NET Core 3 API Tutorial* by Les Jackson-Apress when I came across the following part:

> **That’s our repository sorted for our Create method, what’s next?**

Some points I should mention:

For the time being, the Create method is completed totally and we should move on to completing the next method (for example: the Update method, or Delete method)

Now, I want to know which construction the highlighted sentence has?
for example:

> That's + 'something' + pp + ...

Is the pattern came above correct? If not, can anyone rewrite it in another form for me to understand it better?

Answer (score 2):

It's an informal way of saying "Now we have sorted out the repository for our Create method".

Other similar expressions are "That's you done" (I have finished what I needed to do to you), "That's me told" (You have corrected a mistake I made rather forcibly), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of the question you ask about the grammar. This is an informal comment in a tutorial. In a lecture it would be a transitional remark. I don't think it's worth trying to decide what grammatical construction it exemplifies.

The title of the question asks for the meaning. You may not have that right.  I don't think the sentence says the Create method is done. That would be the case if "for" were replaced by "by".  I would read this as

> We have just sorted the repository, so it is ready for input to our
> Create method. What is the next step?

I would need more context to know for sure.